# MVC User Management by Admin User

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, authorization

I'm trying to get my head round MVC and want to add admin authorised user administration on the site. (i.e. The user can CRUD users of the ApplicationUser class.)

I'm sure this must be in the framework already somewhere - it seems too vanilla to have to roll my own - but I can't find it.

Have googled to no avail, probably because I'm using the wrong terminology. Can anyone point me in the right direction for decent documentation on how to do this?

(The site will be closed, with no public registration - I need the Admin to be able to create new users, edit them, assign roles etc.)

Answer (score 1):

[ASP.NET Boilerplate](https://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/) has Module Zero, which provides user and role management. There is also an article that may interest you [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-5-Security-And-44cbdb97).